# How do I save brushes to use in new documents in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

Why don't brushes that I import into Illustrator save in the library? I'll open a new file and they won't be there any more. Is there a way to make them stay in there permanently?

Comment: Can someone help me with these. Existing answers aren't very helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

Citation:

"You can make the brushes you create available for every new document by adding the brush definition to the [New Document Profile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6330a.html#WSC6B43337-F1E4-4e56-BF59-88257FFC77E4a)"

If you want to "load" the brushes you saved, you click on Brush library icon and choose User-defined brushes:

[image]

Comment: Ohh got it. A bit unnecessary but makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Is creating this New Document Profile necessary? What if directly create a brush folder and copy my brush files there? Then I can find it in Illustrator in every document, buy opening the libraries panel.

Answer (score 2):

To have the brush automatically load without having to import a new library every time, in Illustrator CC 2014:
1) In Illustrator, apply the brush to a path, then copy the object to the pasteboard (effectively copying the brush as well)
2) Go to your "New Document Profiles" folder
*(for me it's: C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator 18 Settings\en_US\x64\New Document Profiles)*
3) Copy and rename any profile template you want to add the brush to (you CAN edit the stock profiles, but I'd strongly recommend against it.)
4) Open your new template in Illustrator
5) Paste the path, and look to see that the brush appears in the brushes pallet
6) Delete the path
7) Close and save your new profile.
To test, create a new Illustrator doc, selecting your new profile's name from the profile drop-down menu. Check the brush pallet. These instructions should work for other versions of Illustrator, but the path to the profiles may differ.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating the brush, saving the file as a template, and open the new documents from that template? It works perfectly and it's fast!