# How to load the illustrator cc default brushes into brush panel?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to reset the brush panel into the default brushes only i have deleted all unused from a blank illustrator doc. but now have nothing but Basic, and Touch Calligraphic Brush showing. I can't find the default brushes. Is there a library with just those initial brushes.This sounds weird but its for teaching beginner Illustrator class-need to demo and need to start with what they have...
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

- Choose `Open Brush Library..` from the **Brush Panel menu**
- Navigate to *any Illustrator file* which contains the default brushes (or any brushes you wish to load) and open that file
- The brushes will load

If you don't know where a file is that may contain the default brushes, simply create a **New Document** and then save it.... then use that new file to load brushes. It will have the default brushes.

It *is* kind of odd that there's no "reset" option for libraries in Illustrator, but there really never has been that option.

This trick works with *any* AI library - brushes, swatches, symbols, graphic styles, etc.

Comment: It seems user has editted the defaults.

Comment: @Scott is there any way to keep the third party brushes imported in Illustrator? Whenever I create a new document, they get lost.

Comment: Post a a new question @Vikas There are possibilities.

Comment: @Scott there's already a question but answers were a bit confusing and not so easy to understand https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36174/how-do-i-save-brushes-to-use-in-new-documents-in-illustrator Seems more technical stuff

Comment: Well, it's going to be technical. @13ruce 's answer there is pretty spot on.